# Character class vs. Lookaround - matching non-existing character at the end of a word.

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, character-class

**q[^x]** – matches “qu” in “question”. It does not match “Iraq” since there is no character after the “q” for the negated character class to match.

**q(?!u)** matches “q” in “Iraq” but not in “question”. (This is a negative lookahead).

The “there is no character after the ‘q’ for the … to match” does not apply? How this can be explained?

Source:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

"Character classes or character sets" and "Lookaround".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative lookahead asserts (not "matches") that

> There is no `u` after `q`

Is there a `u` after the `q` in `Iraq`? No, so the `q` matches (not the `u` though!).

The reverse character class *matches*

> a *character* that is not `u` after `q`.

This implies that there must first be a character after `q`, *and* it has to not be `u`. So `Iraq` does not match.

Comment: also `[^u]` is part of match whereas `(?!u)` isn't

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Edited.